# Python sorting list of different dicts

Tags: python

I have the below list of dict and need to sort on different dicts **per key and value**

```
[{'label': [{'href': '/orgs/x/labels/xx'}]},
 {'ip_list': [{'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/12'},
              {'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/11'}]}]
```

Need this output

```
[{'ip_list': [{'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/11'},
              {'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/12'}]},
 {'label': [{'href': '/orgs/x/labels/xx'}]}]
```

**Also, not always the list of dict will have keys of labels and ip_lists. It might be one or the other or both.**

Or it can be

```
[{'label': [{'href': '/orgs/x/labels/xx'}]},
 {'ip_list': [{'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/12'}]}]
```

I want the output as

```
[{'ip_list': [{'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/12'}]},
{'label': [{'href': '/orgs/x/labels/xx'}]}]
```

Or it can be

```
[{'ip_list': [{'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/12'}, {'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/11'}]}]
```

And I want the output as

```
[{'ip_list': [{'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/11'}, {'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/12'}]}]
```

Comment: This is a bit strange, dicts cannot be compared and are not generally intended to be sorted. Have you considered using a different data structure?

Comment: I think it's not so much that dicts cannot be compared, as you could use a key that all the dicts have as the key to the sorted function. It's more that this list of dicts do not share a consistent key. How do you handle a dict with two or more keys?

Comment: What rule do you apply to decide to sort the list of dicts as shown? Can you provide other examples to help us look for a pattern? Will each dict only every have one key? What if a dict has more than one key? How do you determine the sorting order?

Comment: @jorf.brunning I agree that the most common need I've seen for sorting a list of dicts is when they are homogenous and all have the same keys. But I can also imagine other ways of sorting a list of dicts, such as by the entire list of keys().

Comment: Added more examples. let me know if that helps.

Single element list of dict value with two different keys can be solved with dict1_list.sort(key=lambda x: list(x.keys())[0])

[{'ip_list': [{'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/12'}]},
{'label': [{'href': '/orgs/x/labels/xx'}]}]

But it does not solve sorting the multiple elements value problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda function to sort on the keys.  You can use list() on the keys and use the 0th item, to avoid 'TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable':

```
dict1_list = [{'label': {'href': '/orgs/x/labels/xx'}},
 {'ip_list': [{'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/xx'},
              {'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/xx'}]}]

dict1_list.sort(key=lambda x: list(x.keys())[0])

print(dict1_list)
# [{'ip_list': [{'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/xx'}, {'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/xx'}]}, 
{'label': {'href': '/orgs/x/labels/xx'}}]
```

Comment: You can also use `key=lambda x: next(iter(x.keys()))`.

Comment: @enzo
How to sort by value within value 
```
[{'ip_list': [{'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/12'},
              {'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/11'}]},
 {'label': {'href': '/orgs/x/labels/xx'}}]
```

I want the output as 
```
[{'ip_list': [{'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/11'},
              {'href': '/orgs/x/sec_policy/draft/ip_lists/12'}]},
 {'label': {'href': '/orgs/x/labels/xx'}}]
```